# How separate my realmObjects in multi sync realm?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I have some realmObject(my data model) in my android app and some Sync Realm for example:

realm_url1 = "realm://myserver:9080/~/setting
contain some user setting realmObject

realm_url2 = "realm://myserver:9080/~/app
contain some app realmObject

How i can set what object create in what realm_url? because all of my realmObject has created in all realm_url.
I getInstance to __permission realm to read user permission but all of my realm object create there and __permission not work properly again and i can't restore it to back. Please get me know can separate object is realms.

Comment: What language are you working with (Swift, Java, JavaScript)?

Comment: Oh sorry i work on android app Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a separate schema for each Realm, you can do so by using the `@RealmModule` annotation. You can see how to use it here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas

```
// Create the module
@RealmModule(classes = { Person.class, Dog.class })
public class MyModule {
}

// Set the module in the RealmConfiguration to allow only classes defined by the module.
SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, url)
  .modules(new MyModule())
  .build();

// It is possible to combine multiple modules to one schema.
SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, url)
  .modules(new MyModule(), new MyOtherModule())
  .build();
```

Comment: Hi @Christian Melchior thank's a lot this is mean all other class not create? or this is mean this class are created?